# Трансферная таблица с XML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть задача создать таблицу в базе данных oracle под проект asp.net и сделать для этой таблицы добавление, удаление и редактирование. Но не напрямую записывать изменения в бд а через xml. То есть при добавлении новой записи я должен данные читать в xml файл. Xml файл записывать в специальную таблицу в бд предназначенную для них. И дальше нужно написать сервис который будет из этой таблицы для xml уже записывать изменения в таблицу куда мне нужно и добавить запись. И ещё логировать это всё в текстовый файл. Для создания xml нашёл статью на хзабре. Как помещать xml в бд и дальше переправлять данные в нужную мне таблицу + логирование пока не разобрался. Может быть кто то может подсказать как это реализовать или кто то занимался таким и есть какие нибудь наброски. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

1) Создать и настроить XML DB ресурс (например, корневой каталог) в БД. Про это есть документация https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb16fol.htm#i1042688;

2) Если в этот каталог уложить файл любым нормальным способом (копирование, FTP и прочее), то БД сама будет автоматически распознавать этот файл как дочерний xml-ресурс;

3) Написать представление, которое будет считывать все ресурсы из нужного корня и преобразовывать информацию в них в нужный вид.

Таким образом, стоит просто скопировать xml файл(ы) в нужное место, и уже можно выполнять запрос - информация станет доступна. Если надо, можно так и хранить огромным числом файлов или по job перекладывать из представления в таблицы.